# Odoo v10 : AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'id' when import stock count

Tags: python, odoo-10

Can you guys help me? I don't how to solve this when I want to import stock count

**Error**:

[image]

Comment: No images of code. [ask] and [mre]

Comment: Please replace the image with the error log. You try to get the `id` from `location_ids` which is evaluated to `False`, look at the code at the specified line (line 75 import_inv_adjustment)

Comment: Please add line of code that occurred this error ..